# My decimal numbers get shortened when creating them but not when editing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, numbers, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using gmaps4rails and in order to store the exact coordinates from a user's marker, I use **string data type** for latitude and longitude.

However, even though my lat/long fields on the page get filled with the entire numbers (i.e. `37.79560594600171` and `30.794677734375`), when I check the log, these are the numbers that are inserted: `37.818138` and `30.7336038`. They are approximated somehow?!

BUT then if I edit that item from the edit screen, the entire values get stored without a problem. I can see that in both my log and db.

I also tried with decimals  (with 16 precision and 14 scale) instead of strings. But still, my database would store just an approximated part of a long number and then fill the rest with 0. For instance, something like this: `44.31223760000000`.

I am using Ruby 2 with Rails 4 and mysql as database. But I think the problem would be somehow with activerecord, since it is the one that stores the values in the db?

These are from my new/edit form:

```
  <%= f.label :latitude %>
  <%= f.text_field :latitude %>

  <%= f.label :longitude %>
  <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there are some hidden conversions happening.

Here are a few things you can check:

**(1)** Whenever you are printing numbers to the console the output is generated by `to_s` which at least for floats rounds the value. (Just the returned output, not the original value)

For example `(1.0/10).to_s` returns `"0.1"` but `%.20f" % (1.0/10)` returns `"0.10000000000000000555"` If you try to hunt down your problem, I'd suggest you create a helper to print out decimal numbers without any trunction first, or find another way to display your values without having to question whether the number has been rounded or not.

**(2)** If you are using strings, there is no reason for ActiveRecord to truncate your input. That would be a terrible bug many applications would suffer from. It is more likely that there is another conversion happening, perhaps something like `value.to_f.to_s` or similar. You can test this by inserting characters only. If your value ends up in the database as zero or nil you definitely have a hidden conversion.

**(3)** If you are using decimals, i.e. `BigDecimal` make sure that you are using `BigDecimal` only and no `Float`! Explicitly or by using `to_f`. That way you would introduce rounding problems, too

**(4)** It is also possible that your data doesn't reach your application intact, perhaps because of Javascript or HTML5 inputs (`type=number`) which potentially can reduce the precision. You can verify this by printing out the entire `params` hash in the controller action. (Using [`pp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) or better [`ap`](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print))

**(5)** Check your migration. Make sure you use the correct precision and that the given precision is applied to the database.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for trying to help!
**(1)** I not only checked in the console, but also in the database and the result is the same. 
I created a new item containing _44.85145543217645_ and then display it using `<%= number_with_precision(@item.latitude, :precision => 14) %>`, but I get _44.85378840000000_.
**(2)** I have no conversion in my entire project..
**(3)** I only used decimal.

Comment: What happens if you use strings and enter "asdf" for example? How is that stored in the database?

Comment: I can't enter text from the view because of gmaps4rails validation and I can't find where to remove that. However, I tried updating the latitude in the console, like this: `t.update_attribute(:latitude, "<some long string here>")` and the update worked. I could see the entire string in the database displayed correctly. Does this answer your question?

Comment: OK, at least you can be sure, that it is not ActiveRecord. There must be something happening before, which modifies your data. Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Added one other thing :)

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get pp to work properly, is it okay if I used `logger.debug: "LET'S SEE #{item.attributes.inspect}"` instead, placed inside the create action? This is what I got in my log:
`Parameters: {... "item"=>{"latitude"=>"44.96039291127528", "longitude"=>"23.2965087890625"} ...}
LET'S SEE: {... "latitude"=>"44.96039291127528", "longitude"=>"23.2965087890625" ...}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO 'items' (... 'latitude', 'longitude', ...) VALUES (... 44.9662584, 23.2985518 ...)
   (47.4ms)  COMMIT`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39988/discussion-between-daniel-rikowski-and-watt)

Comment: Does anyone else have any idea?